# Are URLs in JavaScript files relative to JavaScript location or browser?

Tags: javascript, url, location, relative-path

When I use AJAX request in JavaScript file like:

```
... url: "request.php" ...
```

When I am on location (rewrited URL):

```
http://example/some/action/id/
```

And JavaScript is located and linked in meta tags by:

```
... src="http://example/js/ajaxrequest.js" ...
```

Then does the request go to `http://example/some/action/id/request.php` or `http://example/js/request.php`?

If I change request URL to `/request.php` instead of `request.php` then would it go to `http://example/request.php` always?

If I have two working environments, `http://localhost/projectname/` and `http://projectname.com/`, and file structure always looks like this (`projectname.com` is copy of projectname directory):

```
http://localhost/projectname/js/ajaxrequest.js
http://localhost/projectname/request.php
http://projectname.com/js/ajaxrequest.js
http://projectname.com/request.php
```

And I can be on main page and also URL-rewritted addresses like:

```
http://localhost/projectname/
http://projectname.com/
http://localhost/projectname/some/action/id/
http://projectname.com/some/action/id/
```

And I want that URL to request in JavaScript file will it work in all of those conditions, or should I put address like `url: "../request.php"` in JavaScript file?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

URIs in JavaScript are only ever inserted into objects associated with that *document*, so are relative to the document URI and not the JS src URI.

a. The former

b. Yes

c. I'd very strongly suggest that you keep the distance of any path from the root the same across all your environments. Either set up virtual name hosting locally, or use something like Charles Proxy to rewrite your domain name over your local testing environment.

Answer (score 1):

On our company's dev server we had a similar problem. We solved it by using subdomains rather then folders. So it's `projectname.localhost/some/action/id/`.